# Book recommendation: agent based modeling?

Tags: reference-request, computation

Is there a book along these criteria?

- introductory
- discuss both theory and writing program
- focus on social science (economics / politics / sociology)

There are bunch of tutorials on the Internet, but journal articles tend not to have code, and a lot of work is not relevant to social science. Thus I think I'll get better recommendation from Econs SE.

Comment: Do yo mean "numerical anaylsis" on Matlab, Mathematica etc. for writing program ?

Comment: The most common language I've seen mentioned is NetLogo, with Python / Java / Matlab coming in second (for people who really dislike NetLogo as a programming language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another book that comes to mind (in keeping with the 1 book per answer guideline) is the Quant-Econ book that is being put together by Tom Sargent and John Stachurski. This book is a little more geared towards programming than John's Economic Dynamics book and can be found (for free) online at http://quant-econ.net/.

All of the book's code is on github and I think it provides a pretty strong introduction to the two programming languages that it uses (Python and Julia).

Comment: The included link is now dead.

Answer (score 2):

One book that comes to mind is "Economic Dynamics" by John Stachurski [found here](http://johnstachurski.net/edtc.html).

This book discusses programming methods that are applied to economics. All of its accompanying code is kept on [this](https://github.com/jstac/edtc-code) github repository.